# Is it necessary to know some programming language before learning to use Unity

Tags: unity

I had learnt a bit of Java programming in school...is there any other programming language that I should learn to be able to work using Unity?

Comment: Unity uses c#, which I see as being a mix of c++ and Java. You might want to learn a bit of c# before starting to use Unity.

Comment: On another note, this type of question is considered off-topic here. Once you start working with Unity, or making any game with c# (you can even make a simple console game with it), you're more than welcome to ask about specific issues you're getting while you're working on it. Once you have sufficient reputation (20--across all stack exchange sites), you'll be able to use our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development), where stuff that is off topic here is more welcome there.